# How to use parameters from the Url to use it in controller method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[image: My Url]

Controller method

```
def status
  @st = params[:st_type].to_i
  @user_id = params[:user_id]
  @post_id = params[:pt_id]
  @a = Apply.find_by_user_id_and_post_id(@user_id, @post_id)
  @a.update_attributes(status: @st)
  flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
end
```

Link doesn't passes the post_id parameter-:

[image]

Link from the views

```
<%= link_to "Shortlist", status_applies_path(:user_id => @user.id, :pt_id => @post_id, :st_type => 1) %>
```

I am trying to get user_id and post_id from the from the url and pass it to my controller method 'def status'. Where it process the user_id and post_id to find the Apply id which further updates the attribute. 
The problem is I am able to fetch only user_id and not the post_id.

Comment: you are not getting `Apply` or not getting ` @post_id = params[:pt_id]`

Comment: not getting post_id itself.

Comment: can you please post what params you are getting in log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that if a value in the URL helper is **nil**, it gets omitted

```ruby
$ rails c
app.jedis_path(listing: 1)
=> "/jedis?listing=1"
app.jedis_path(listing: nil)
=> "/jedis"
```

So your syntax is correct, but if the param gets to the helper URL method as **nil**, it is not displayed in the URL per se

Answer (score 0):

use `where` and `first`

```
Apply.where(something_attr: @user_id, other_attr: @post_id).first
```

Comment: I will change that but the link is not passing the pt_id parameter to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Its silly typo

You are passing params as `:post_id` and fetching it as `params[:pt_id]` change it to:

```
@post_id = params[:post_id]
```

Comment: I was trying many things as it was not working, even :pt_id isnt working, as it is not passing the parameter. I have updated my question and attached the screenshot of the url that is being called.

Comment: make sure there is some value in `@post_id`

Comment: In the url it shows 'post_id=1', is there any other way to fix this?

Comment: then in your controller change `@post_id = params[:post_id]`

Comment: That won't help as the link_to is not sending the post_id parameter.

Comment: then from where are you sending the parameter post_id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123331/discussion-between-deepak-and-tanuj).